# On Interface Builder connect UILabel to custom UIView IBOutlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, iboutlet

I'm developing an iOS app with latest SDK.

I have created a custom class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UICustomView : UIView
{
    @private
    int _counter;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* textField;

@end
```

On Storyboad I have added a `UIView` and changed its class to `UICustomView`. To this `UIView` I have added an `UILabel` using Interface Builder but now I don't know how to connect this `UILabel` with the `IBOutlet` on the custom view.

**Do you know how can I do it?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

New approach (which I've tested)

Select your `UICustomView` in Interface builder and you should see your `UILabel` in the inspector to the right under "Outlets". Drag that to your label to connect it.

[image]

Comment: @VansFannel see my new answer instead